# R: Use replace function with multiple index criteria

Tags: r, replace

Is there a way to handle multiple conditionals at once using replace?

What I have now is a `data.frame` and want to keep it a `data.frame`:

```
names$first <- replace(names$first, names$first=="kevin", "Kevin")
```

works fine, but I want to be able to handle multiple criteria by avoiding `if_else` if possible. Is something like the below possible? The documentation is sparse and has no examples.

```
names$first <- replace(names$first, c("kevin","susan"), c("Kevin","Susan"))
```

Comment: library stringr, function str_replace allows multiple replacements

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)    
names = data.frame(first = c("kevin", "susan", "anbreen"))
str_replace_all(names$first, c("kevin" = "Kevin", "susan" = "Susan"))

#[1] "Kevin"   "Susan"   "anbreen"
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in `replace` is an index vector.  What you would need here is something like

```
kevins <- which(names$first == "kevin")
susans <- which(names$first == "susan")
replace(names(first), c(kevins, susans),
        c(rep("Kevin", length(kevins)), rep("Susan", length(susans))))
```

But like @epi99 said, there are packages with functions to do this, if you don't mind leaving base R.  I hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you mean about there being easier ways. Do you think dplyr has a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways assuming this input:

```
from <- c("kevin", "susan")
to <- c("Kevin", "Susan")
Names <- data.frame(first = c("kevin", "susan", "joe"), stringsToFactors = FALSE)
```

**1) match** This is a base R solution:

```
first <- Names$first
From <- c(from, first)
To <- c(to, first)
Names$first <- To[match(first, From)]
```

The above could be written as one line but might not be as clear.

**2) gsubfn**

```
library(gsubfn)
Names$first <- gsubfn(".*", as.list(setNames(to, from)), Names$first)
```

**3) Reduce**  This one does use `replace`.  It is also a base R solution.

```
repl <- function(x, i) replace(x, x == from[i], to[i])
Names$first <- Reduce(repl, init = Names$first, seq_along(from))
```

**4) for** A `for` loop is another base solution and uses `replace` and is simple:

```
for(i in seq_along(from)) {
    Names$first <- with(Names, replace(first, first == from[i], to[i]))
}
```

Comment: One thought I had about a "safer" way to use the `Reduce` was to use a list and set use the names attribute: `Reduce(function(ini,x) replace(ini, ini == x, names(x)), x = list(setNames("kevin","Kevin"), setNames("susan","Susan")), init = names)
`